# ajax posting of new sorted jquery datalist to get the position of newly settled rows asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, row, jquery-ui-sortable, datalistitem

```
$(window).load(function () {
   $("table").sortable({
     items: "div",
     opacity: 0.6,
     cursor: 'move',
     update: function (event, ui) {
       var order = $('#form1').serialize();
       $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "Default7.aspx/Update",
         data: "{'NewOrder': '" + order + "'}",
         dataType: "json",
         contentType: "application/json"
       });
     }
   });
 }); 


[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static void Update(string NewOrder)
{
}
```

how can i alert the newly sorted rows?

Comment: Please take some time and properly format your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("table").sortable({ items: "div", opacity: 0.6, cursor: 'move', update: function (event, ui) {
         var order = $('#form1').serialize();
         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "Default7.aspx/Update",
             data: {"NewOrder" : order },
             dataType: "json",
             contentType: "application/json",
             success:function(){// add success callback function to sort row
                // add you code to sort the table
                // or call $('table').sortable() again
             }
         });
       }
   });
});
```

Comment: What should i write in webservice method, so i will get the response or requested ajax

Comment: [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string Update(string[] NewOrder)
    {
        string a = "";
        foreach (var item in NewOrder)
        {
            a = a + item;
        }
        return a;
}
}
is this going to work?????

Comment: Do you want `order` as `asc` or `desc`